# write_file in readr Error in open.connection(path, "ab") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, readr

I am using a loop to write a large text file. it's like this:

```
 for(f in allf){
    print(f)
    fText = getText(f)
    write_file(x = fText, path = fileName, append = T)
  }
```

I sometimes get the following error but not always:

```
Error in open.connection(path, "ab") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(path, "ab") :
  cannot open file 'fileName' : Permission denied
```

If I add a pause like this

```
 for(f in allf){
    print(f)
    fText = getText(f)
    Sys.sleep(.2)
    write_file(x = fText, path = fileName, append = T)
  }
```

I dont get any issues, but if I use less than 0.2 I still get the error.

Is this an antivirus issue? I don't think it's a `write_file` bug, as it should be safe to append after the function exists.

I am on windows 7 with no admin rights:

```
> session_info()
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2018-09-11
```

Comment: are you using windows? have you tried running r as admin?

Comment: yes and no. Added sessioninfo above